# If $\lim_{x\to 0} (2+(f(x)/x^2))^{1/x} = e^2$ and $f(x)=a_0 + a_1x+a_2x^2...$, then prove that $a_2+|a_3|=1$.

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

> If $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(2+\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\right)^{\frac 1x} = e^2$$ and $f(x)=a_0 + a_1x+a_2x^2...$, then prove that $$a_2+|a_3|=1\,.$$

The function seems to be of the form $\infty^{\infty}$.

I don’t know how to start solving it, since it an indeterminate form I don’t know how to evaluate. Can I gain some insight into the question?

EDIT:-

$$y=\lim_{x\to 0} (2+\frac{f(x)}{x^2})^{\frac 1x}$$
$$\log y = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac 1x \log (2+\frac{f(x)}{x^2})$$
$$\log y = \frac 1x (1+\frac{f(x)}{x^2})=2$$

Comment: No it should be 1 raise to power infty

Comment: What about looking at logarithms?

Comment: You can take logarithms and make use of the standard limit $\lim\limits _{t\to 0}\dfrac{\log(1+t)}{t}=1$.

Comment: From the limit condition,
$$\left(2+\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\right)^{\frac1x}=\text{e}^2\big(1+o(1)\big)$$
for small values of $x$.  Show that this means
$$f(x)=-2x^2+x^2\,\text{e}^{2x}\,\big(1+o(x)\big)=-2x^2+x^2\,\big(1+2x+O(x^2)\big)\,\big(1+o(x)\big)$$
for small values of $x$.  This implies
$$f(x)=-x^2+2x^3+o(x^3)$$
for small values of $x$.  Unless $f$ is analytic at $0$, I don't think you can expand $f$ further than this.

Comment: @Batominovski: although this is not explicitly given, a proper interpretation could be that $f(x) $ satisfies the relation $f(x) =a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+o(x^3)$ as $x\to 0$. Based on this we can find the coefficients $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$ uniquely.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I tried using logs, and got $\frac 1x + \frac{f(x)}{x^3}=2$

Comment: @Aditya: it would be best if you can show the details in question. You should get $(1/x)+(f(x)/x^3)\to 2$ and not equal to $2$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I don’t know what difference does using $\to$ and $=$ make other than being purely symbolic. Can you please elaborate

Comment: The $=$ in your comments determines $f$ uniquely whereas the $\to $ sign does not guarantee a unique $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a difficult question, but a rigorous answer requires some effort and an understanding of limit laws.

As mentioned in my comment to the question I will assume that $$f(x) =a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+o(x^3)\tag{1}$$ as $x\to 0$. For those not well versed with the little-o notation the above equation is by definition equivalent to $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x) - a_0-a_1x-a_2x^2-a_3x^3}{x^3}=0\tag{2}$$ The given limit condition in question is equivalent to $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(2+(f(x)/x^2))}{x}=2\tag{3}$$ (this uses the fact that log is continuous and invertible).

And then $$\log\left(2+\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\right)=x\cdot\frac{\log(2+(f(x)/x^2))}{x}\to 0\cdot 2=0$$ as $x\to 0$. Exponentiating  this we see that $$2+\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\to 1$$ as $x\to 0$ (this works because exponentiation is also continuous) or $$\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\to - 1\tag{4}$$ as $x\to 0$. Multiplying by $x$ and $x^2$ we see that $f(x) /x\to 0$ and $f(x) \to 0$.

Now using $(1)$ or $(2)$ with $f(x)\to 0$ we get $a_0=0$. Next using $a_0=0,f(x)/x\to 0$ with $(1)$ we get $a_1=0$. And in similar fashion we get $a_2=-1$ using $(1)$ and $(4)$.

To get $a_3$ we need to use equation $(3)$ also. Since the limit in $(3)$ is non-zero it follows from $(4)$ that $t=1+(f(x)/x^2)\to 0, t\neq 0$ as $x\to 0$ and $(3)$ can then be rewritten as $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{t}{x}\cdot\frac{\log(1+t)}{t}=2$$ Since $(\log(1+t))/t\to 1$ as $t\to 0$ it follows that $$\frac{t} {x} =\frac{1}{x}+\frac{f(x)}{x^3}\to 2\tag{5}$$ Using $(2)$ and $(5)$ along with the values $$a_0=a_1=0,a_2=-1$$ we get $a_3=2$.

---

The flaw in your approach is that you remove the limit operator without any justification. This simply does not work and can not be guaranteed.

Comment: Can you please clarify how you arrived at $2+\frac{f(x)}{x^2} \to 1$

Comment: @Aditya: I have proved that the log of this expression tends to $0$. Applying $\exp $ function on this we get that the expression tends to $1$.

Comment: Why does the log tend to 0?

Comment: @Aditya: read my answer after equation $(3)$.

Comment: You multiplied and divided by $x$, and used $x\to 0$ to get the whole function $g(x)\to 0$. Doesnt that feel like cheating though?

Comment: @Aditya: why does that sound like cheating? It is based on well founded limit laws and usual rules of multiplication. It is just a way of figuring out the unknown from known and you need to be able to express the unknown in terms of known to get what you need. What is known here is equation $(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma**: If $\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow 0}(1+g(x))^{\frac{1}{x}}=e^2$, then $\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)=0$.

**Proof of the Lemma**: First, we know that $1+g(x)>0$ (see:https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2Bx%29%5E%7B1%2Fx%7D)

If $\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)\neq 0$, by definition of limit, there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ and sequence $x_n\rightarrow 0$ and a small enough $\delta$ (say $\delta=10^{-10}$, anyway) when $|x_n|<\delta$, we have $g(x_n)\geq \epsilon_0$ or $g(x_n)\leq -\epsilon_0$.

Now we consider the part of $\delta>x_n>0$ to construct a contradiction.

(i) if $g(x_n)\geq \epsilon_0$, then
$$(1+g(x_n))^{\frac{1}{x_n}}\geq(1+\epsilon_0)^{\frac{1}{x_n}}\geq(1+\epsilon_0)^{\delta^{-1}}>e^2$$ ($t^{1/x_n}$ is increasing, $\delta$ small enough)

(ii) if $g(x_n)\leq -\epsilon_0$
$$0<(1+g(x_n))^{\frac{1}{x_n}}\leq(1-\epsilon_0)^{\frac{1}{x_n}}\leq(1-\epsilon_0)^{\delta^{-1}}<e^2$$
($t^{1/x_n}$ is increasing, $\delta$ small enough)

Contradiction. The lemma is proved.

Now back to the problem. By the lemma we have $\frac{f(x)}{x^2}+1$ goes to $0$, that is
$$\frac{a_0}{x^2}+\frac{a_1}{x}+a_2+a_3x+o(x)+1\rightarrow 0$$
So $a_0=a_1=0$, $a_2=-1$.
Now
$$(2+\frac{f(x)}{x^2})^{1/x}=(1+a_3x+o(x))^{1/x}=\\
(1+a_3 x+o(x))^{\frac{1}{a_3 
 x+o(x)}\cdot~~~~~\frac{a_3 
 x+o(x)}{x}}\rightarrow e^{a_3}=e^2$$

So $a_3=2$